# Print json element separately

Tags: javascript, php, json

My json return value as

```
"name":"[\"nine\",\"tweleve\",\"four\"]"
```

How can i print Nine tweleve and four separately.

i used

$time1 = json_decode($row['time']);

where `$row['time']` returns the above json.

I tried,

```
<?php echo $time1->{'name'}; 
              ?>
```

But it prints like

```
["nine","tweleve","four"]
```

even

```
 <?php echo $time1->{'name'}[0]; 
                  ?>
```

doesn't help.

Comment: Please define *"doesn't help"* what does it print? Is it not what you expected?

Comment: It is printing like a string , <?php echo $time1->{'name'}[0]; 
                  ?>  print only '['  i want 'nine' then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `"name"` is not a JSON array, it is a JSON string. Thus, you need to JSON decode the "name" string as well.

```
$time1 = json_decode($row['time']);
$time1name = json_decode($time1->{'name'})
```

and then

```
<? php echo $time1name[0]; ?>
```

should print `"nine"`.

---

If possible, you should format your JSON correctly so that it is an actual JSON array like so:

```
"name": ["nine","tweleve","four"]
```

Notice no `"`s around the array brackets (`[`,`]`).

Answer (score 0):

You should remember you browser only recognizes html. It doesn't know what json is? Thus it is recommended to add header like this: 
`header('Content-Type: application/json');`
Then you should first encode data into json like this:
`echo json_encode($results, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`
Remember the solution I am giving here obviously for php>5.4.

Comment: i am inserting data into sql table through php by encoding like this, $time['name'] = json_encode($this->input->post('time')); i am using code ignitor